# PHP XML Output from mySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am pulling information from an SQL database and forming it as XML via PHP. I am attempting to make my XML format like this:

```
<channel>
    <channel_name>ASN</channel_name>
    <program id="1">
        <title>The Simpson</title>
        <info>Melfi considers turning to Homer for help...</info>
        <season>S01</season>
        <episode>E09</episode>
        ...
        <channel>ASN</channel>
    </program>
</channel>
<channel>
    <channel_name>NBC</channel_name>
    <program id="2">
        <title>The Simpson</title>
        <info>Melfi considers turning to Homer for help...</info>
        <season>S02</season>
        <episode>E04</episode>
        ...
        <channel>NBC</channel>
    </program>
</channel>
...etc
```

This is my PHP that is attempting to mimic the XML structure above:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
    include_once "db_connect.php";
    //SQL Query
    $program_sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT * FROM Programs
SQL;
    if ($result = $db->query($program_sql)) {
        /* fetch associative array */
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            //Data
            #Descriptions
            $program_title = $row['program_title'];
            $program_id = $row['program_id'];
            $program_info = $row['program_info'];
            #Guides
            $program_season = $row['program_season'];
            $program_episode = $row['program_episode'];
            $program_genre = $row['program_genre'];
            #Times
            $program_duration_hours = $row['program_duration_hours'];
            $program_duration_mins = $row['program_duration_mins'];
            $program_day = $row['program_day'];
            $program_time_start = $row['program_time_start'];
            $program_time_end = $row['program_time_end'];
            #Assets
            $program_image_fullsize = $row['program_image_fullsize'];
            $program_image_thumbnail = $row['program_image_thumbnail'];
            #Channel
            $channel .= $row['channel'];
            //XML Output
            $output .= "<program id='".$program_id."'>
        <title>".$program_title."</title>
        <info>".$program_info."</info>
        <season>S".$program_season."</season>
        <episode>E".$program_episode."</episode>
        <duration>
            <hours>".$program_duration_hours."</hours>
            <minutes>".$program_duration_mins."</minutes>
        </duration>
        <day>".$program_day."</day>
        <time>
            <start>".$program_time_start."</start>
            <end>".$program_time_end."</end>
        </time>
        <genre>".$program_genre."</genre>
        <image>
            <fullsize>/images/program_images/".$program_image_fullsize."</fullsize>
            <thumbnail>/images/program_images/thumbnails/".$program_image_thumbnail."</thumbnail>
        </image>
        <channel>".$channel."</channel>
    </program>";
        }//Channel While Loop
    }//if

    echo $output;
    mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

My PHP is currently only outputting the program node; How would I go about wrapping these in their corresponding channel tags?

Comment: The channel tag has multiple program tags?

Comment: well we don't know what these tables look inside, but just try to do same logic as you have already done. fetch the values then make another one for the channel. your already done the program right?

Comment: Yeah @alu there are Multiple program tags :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$rows = [
    ['channel_name' => 'ASN', 'program_id' => 1, 'program_title' => 'Program 1'],
    ['channel_name' => 'ASN', 'program_id' => 2, 'program_title' => 'Program 2'],
    ['channel_name' => 'NBC', 'program_id' => 3, 'program_title' => 'Program 3'],
];

// pre grouping pattern
$grouped = array_reduce($rows, function($channels, $row) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row['channel_name'], $channels)) {
        $channels[$row['channel_name']] = [];
    }
    $channels[$row['channel_name']][] = $row;

    return $channels;
}, []);

foreach ($grouped as $channelName => $program) {
    // build up XML
}

// Or SimpleXML pattern
$root = new SimpleXMLElement('<root />');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $channel = $root->xpath("/root/channel/channel_name[text()='{$row['channel_name']}']/parent::node()");
    if (count($channel) === 0) {
        $channel = $root->addChild('channel');
        $channel->addChild('channel_name', $row['channel_name']);
    } else {
        $channel = $channel[0];
    }

    $program = $channel->addChild('program');
    $program->addAttribute('id', $row['program_id']);
    $program->addChild('title', $row['program_title']);
}

echo $root->asXML();
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much— Just one quick query, How would I go about populating that $rows (array right?) from a database? Apologies for the pestering, I am a little green with PHP. Thanks again!

Comment: The `$rows` is example. You can use while loop on the your original code (foreach to while).